# How to detect a scrolling word like marquee word has reached the edge of web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, scroll, marquee

I have an application need to detect whether a scrolling word like marquee has reached the edge of a web browser.

Currently, I am using Marquee HTML tag and inner HTML with asp.net to simulate the pattern but unfortunately, I could not find a way to detect it.

My current thinking is to add in start code and end code for the content of marquee so that I can detect if the start of the code has reached the edge of the web browser.

But I cannot find a DOM or control to help to detect the action.

Anyone can help it? Appreciate it!

Below code is I am trying to access the value of a div in c# asp.net code behind.

The example of start code can be "!!" and end code "**".

```
   <marquee id="mar1" Height="32px" style="font-family:'Adobe Arabic'; color: #FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000">
           <div id="contentDiv1" runat="server">
            </div></marquee>
      <marquee id="mar1" Height="32px" style="font-family:'Adobe Arabic'; color: #FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000">
           <div id="contentDiv2" runat="server">
             </div>

        <asp:Button ID="btnConvert" runat="server" Text="Convert To txt" />


         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />

    <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('contentDiv1');
    var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('contentDiv2');
    MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;

       function test() {
        var p = $("#testID");
        var position = p.position();
        document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = position.top;
           document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField2.ClientID %>').value = position.left;
           alert(position.top + position.left);
    }

</script> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="test()" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding I assume you are planning to move text from one end to another end of the screen. Once you reach the edge you have to detect that it has reached end of the screen. My suggestion is to use HTML5 canvas or SVG for this purpose where you can track the position of objects in a much easier way. It would be good if you can share screenshots of your code and web page output.

Comment: FYI: Screenshots of code is not a good idea at all ([You can read here why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)) and would probably get the question closed (And probably downvoted), but the actual code **as text** would be most welcome :)